Context is resetting when i navigate to other page
I was using the context which is
import  { createContext, useState } from 'react';
export const IsSignedUpContext = createContext();


export const IsSignedUpProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const [isSignedUp, setIsSignedUp] = useState(false); 
  console.log(isSignedUp);

  return (
    <IsSignedUpContext.Provider value={{ isSignedUp, setIsSignedUp }}>
      {children}
    </IsSignedUpContext.Provider>
  );
};

and the App.js is
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { IsSignedUpProvider } from "./context/Context";

import "./App.css";
import Inbox from "./pages/inbox";

function App() {
  console.log("render")
  return (
  
    <IsSignedUpProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
   
        <div className="App">
         <NavbarSimple/>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>}/>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Protected><Dashboard/></Protected>}/>
          <Route path="/Signup" element={<Protected><SignUpForm/></Protected>} />
          <Route path="/viewbooks" element={<Protected><Viewbooks/></Protected>} />
          <Route path="/Forum" element={<Protected><Forum/></Protected>}/>
          <Route path="/userprofile" element={<Protected><UserProfile /></Protected>} />
          <Route path="/forum/:id" element={<Protected><Postpage/></Protected>}/>
          <Route path="/chat" element={<Protected><Chat/></Protected>}/>
          <Route path="/inbox" element={<Protected><Inbox/></Protected>}/>
        </Routes>
        </div>
    
  </BrowserRouter>
  </IsSignedUpProvider>

    

  );
}

export default App;

so, I initially set isSignedUp to true in the NavbarSimple component. When routed to any other component from NavbarSimple, the isSignedUp context is set to false again. I have made sure i havent called setIsSignedup anywhere else other than that one place in NavbarSimple.
I tried Wrapping the provider on App but it still doesnt work.

Are you possibly using <a> for your links instead of <Link> from react-router? In that case your browser will navigate to that page, which means it refetches the HTML and loads the page, which means any JS state is thrown out.

@cbr Yes that was the problem, i just realised now why my navbar was re rendering everytime I navigated to another page. Thank you very much.
